# Not able to show UIPickerView inside UIAlertController on iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

Earlier I was using UIactionSheet but since that has been deprecated I am trying to use UIAlertController to show a UIPicker.
Here is the piece of code I am using to add the picker to UIAlertController.

```
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"some_title"
                                                                             message:nil
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    [alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
    [alertController.view addSubview:_formatPickerView];
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController
                                                     popoverPresentationController];
    // cell is a cell from a tableview
    popPresenter.sourceView = cell;
    popPresenter.sourceRect = cellRect;
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This brings up the AlertController but **without** the Picker.

an interesting observation is that if I change the `preferredStyle` in

`[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"some_title"
                                     message:nil                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];`

from `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` to `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` then I start getting the Picker but I lose the control over the position of the UIAlertController.

I want the control over the position of the UIAlertController so I am using `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`

Has anyone seen this problem before ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by showing a `UIPickerView` inside a `UIActionSheet`.

```
UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    actionSheet.delegate = self;
    [actionSheet addSubview:_formatPickerView];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect cellRect = cell.bounds;
    cellRect.size.width = cell.frame.size.width * 2;
    cellRect.origin.x = -(cell.frame.size.width/2);

    [actionSheet showFromRect:cellRect inView:cell animated:YES];
```